# Create an array of objects by duplicating

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, redux

Write a function which takes the following input and return an array of objects(of length 10) by duplicating object by incrementing its id;

The visible must be true for output[0] and false for remaining.

```
   input:
   {   id: 0,
        visible: true,
        width: 200 ;
        height: 200;
   }

   output:
   [ {   id: 0,
        visible: true,
        width: 200 ;
        height: 200;
    },
    {   id: 1,
        visible: false,
        width: 200 ;
        height: 200;
    },{   id: 2,
        visible: false,
        width: 200 ;
        height: 200;
    },{   id: 3,
        visible: false,
        width: 200 ;
        height: 200;
    },.
     .
     .
     .
   {   id: 9,
        visible: false,
        width: 200 ;
        height: 200;
    }]
```

Comment: Nice, can you post some code, please? We will be glad to help

Comment: Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it. Please read [How to ask homework questions](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and [edit] your post.

Comment: `const output = input => Array.from({length:10}, index => index === 0 ? input : Object.assign({}, input, {visible: false, id: index}); console.log(output(input));`

Answer (score 2):

You can create a 10 element array, fill it with `0` (or anything, the fill just enables iteration) and then `map` over it and return a copy of the input with the desired id on each iteration:

**Edit:** updated to include the logic for `visible` (missed it on first post)

```js
const input = { id: 0, visible: true, width: 200, height: 200 };

const output = Array(10).fill(0).map((x, id) => ({...input, visible: id === 0, id}));

console.log(output)
```

Comment: `Array.from({length:10}, (x, id) => ({...input, visible: id === 0, id}));` is the shortest version and faster

Comment: Nice improvement!

Answer (score 0):

Here's my draft, however if you intend to get a good answer you are also expected to show us what you have tried and where you went stuck before asking us to spend our time doing everything for you.

```
const mock = {
    id: 0,
    visible: true,
    width: 200,
    height: 200
}

let mockArr = [];

for (i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    mockArr.push({
        ...mock,
        visible: i === 0,
        id: i
    })
}
console.log(mockArr)
```

Answer (score 0):

My proposal...

```js
let input = { id: 0, visible: true,  width: 200, height: 200 }

let output = [];

for (let i=0; i<10; i++) {
  output.push( Object.assign({}, input, { id: i, visible:(i===0) }) )
}
 
console.log(output);
```